# windows batch command for loop set environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically build en environment variable that contains a list of JAR files under my app's WEB-INF/lib folder.

This is what I have so far, but it's over-writing itself each time, so when you reach the end of the loop, you just have the last file from the loop set in the variable.

```
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f IN (WEB-INF/lib/*.jar) DO (

  SET JAR_LIST=%JAR_LIST%;%%f

)

ECHO JAR_LIST -- %JAR_LIST%
```

So this produces...

> C:\apache\Tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp>(SET JAR_LIST=.;xsltcbrazil.jar )
>
> C:\apache\Tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp>(SET JAR_LIST=.;xsltcejb.jar )
>
> C:\apache\Tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp>(SET JAR_LIST=.;xsltcservlet.jar )
>
> C:\apache\Tomcat6.0\webapps\myapp>ECHO JAR_LIST -- .;xsltcservlet.jar
>
> JAR_LIST -- .;xsltcservlet.jar

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
SET JAR_LIST=%JAR_LIST%;%%f
```

to

```
SET JAR_LIST=!JAR_LIST!;%%f
```

This will use the run-time value instead of the load-time value.
It might be better to do this to avoid the leading ;

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "JAR_LIST="
for %%f IN (WEB-INF/lib/*.jar) DO (
if "!JAR_LIST!"=="" (SET JAR_LIST=%%f) ELSE (SET JAR_LIST=!JAR_LIST!;%%f)
)
ECHO JAR_LIST -- %JAR_LIST%
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774259/issue-with-setting-environment-variable-through-bat-file-to-execute-a-java-progr.  If you want to use the variable later, you need `ENDLOCAL & SET JAR_LIST=%JAR_LIST%`.