# How to set command output as variable in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, command-prompt, mediainfo

First, I've googled and googled how to fix this problem, with no luck. I'm working on making a batch file to re-encode audio in a file to aac if it's ac-3 or ogg using ffmpeg. I know how to do the conversion with ffmpeg, just not how to automate it only if the audio matches a certain codec. To get the audio codec for the file, I have two different methods, one with ffprobe, and the other with MediaInfo.

```
MediaInfo --Inform="Audio;%%Format%%" "input.mkv"
```

or

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "input.mkv"
```

However, my issue is with setting a variable from the command output. This is the code I've been trying, to no avail.

```
SETLOCAL

for %%a in (*.mp4) do (

MediaInfo --Inform="Audio;%%Format%%" "%%a">codec.txt

SET /p codec=<codec.txt

DEL codec.txt

ECHO %codec%

)

pause
```

Obviously, this is only a section of my goal, but this is the part I can't seem to get past. I have checked, by removing the "DEL codec.txt" part, that is in fact storing the correct output in the text file, but it's not importing it into the variable. Anyway I can set the output to a variable is fine, this is just the way I often found in my search.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows batch command for loop set environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598638/windows-batch-command-for-loop-set-environment-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch - Assign Command output to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/batch-assign-command-output-to-variable); also related: [Batch - Assign Command output with variables to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663803/batch-assign-command-output-with-variables-to-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
 for /f "delims=" %%c in (
  'MediaInfo --Inform="Audio;%%Format%%" "%%a" ') do (

  echo codec is %%c
  rem now use "%%c" as codec
 )
 rem "%%c" is now out-of-scope
)
```

You'd need to search SO for `delayed expansion` for an explanation of why `codec` remained unchanged in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked with a slight modification. I had to add a caret before the equals sign, since it wasn't passing that as part of the command.